# Jmeter + Maven: how to add a jar file to JMeter /lib/ext folder

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have a Jmeter-Maven project and I'd like to put a modified **jar** file in **"/lib/ext"** folder.

I've added it to “**/src/test/jmeter/lib/ext**”, but seems it doesn't work.

Do I need to add dependencies to my POM file or so?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 3):

You can add libraries to "lib/ext" folder as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <jmeterExtensions>
        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.4</artifact>
    </jmeterExtensions>
</configuration>
```

Replace `kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.4` with your own artifact in form of:

```
groupId:artifactId:version
```

References:

- [Guide to naming conventions on groupId, artifactId and version](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html)
- [Adding jar's to the /lib/ext directory](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include an external JAR file into your JMeter tests within a Maven project, follow these steps:

1. Locate JMeter User Classpath:

Review the JMeter documentation to understand how to use the user.classpath property. This property allows you to specify additional classpath entries.

2. Add JAR to your project:

Place your JAR file in to some folder of your Maven project.
If the JAR is built within the same project, ensure it's compiled before your JMeter tests run.

3. Configure jmeter-maven-plugin:

In your pom.xml, configure the jmeter-maven-plugin to include path to the directory with your JAR.
Add user.classpath with the path value to propertiesJmeter

Documentation for propertiesJmeter: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#adding-additional-properties-to-propertiesjmeter